# Google Sheets concatenate a 2d array into a single column and sort simultaneously

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation

I want to know if it is possible and if so how I can achieve converting an array of 8 columns and 300+ rows into a sorted, concatenated, one-dimensional array where each row is the concatenation of the contents in the 8 columns. I would also like to achieve this using a single formula.

**Example:**

```
leg | dog | tom | jon | bar |     |     |     |
foo | bin | git | hub | bet | far | day | bin |
...
```

**would convert into:**

```
bar dog jon leg tom
bet bin bin day far foo git hub
...
```

I can achieve this for a single row using this:

```
=arrayformula(CONCATENATE(transpose(sort(transpose(F2:M2),1,1))&" "))
```

as long as the 8 columns are from F to M
I can then copy this formula down 300+ times which is easy to do but I would like a single formula that populates *n* number of rows.

Can this be achieved or do I have to copy the formula down?

Comment: Hi Ben, can you share a spreadsheet with some data and shows us the expected outcome?

Comment: Should the sorting only be horizontal, or vertical as well?

Comment: The sorting only needed to be horizontal, since vertically sorting the resultant list is as simple as wrapping the formula in a sort()

Comment: I was able to take a (2D) table and transform it into a (1D) table: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172747/135478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do that:

```
=transpose(split(" "&join(" ",index(sort(arrayformula({row(A1:A300),len(A1:A300)*0-9E+99
                                                      ;row(A1:A300),A1:A300
                                                      ;row(A1:A300),B1:B300
                                                      ;row(A1:A300),C1:C300
                                                      ;row(A1:A300),D1:D300
                                                      ;row(A1:A300),E1:E300
                                                      ;row(A1:A300),F1:F300
                                                      ;row(A1:A300),G1:G300
                                                      ;row(A1:A300),H1:H300
                                                      })),0,2))," "&-9E+99&" ",false))
```

First it creates a two-dimensional array with original row number in the first column and value in the second for each cell (adding a new value -9e99 for each row), then the array is sorted, first column is discarded, all values are joined using a space, then split (by the added value surrounded by spaces), and finally transposed.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood correctly, you should be able to do that with a formula like this

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(query(transpose(A2:H8),,50000)))
```

Change the range to suit.
See also below picture.

[image]

EDIT: An alternative way may be to create a custom formula (sorting included). Add this to the script editor

```
function concatenateAndSort(range) {
  return range.map(function (r) {
  return [r.sort().join(" ")]
})
}
```

Then in the spreadsheet (where you want the output to appear) enter

```
=concatenateAndSort(A3:H8)
```

(Change range to suit).

Comment: The sorting in each row is missing.

Comment: @Mik: correct. Seems I forgot about that. Added a new solution using a custom function. See if that works ?

Comment: is there a way to avoid the "space" among results? Example: A2B2C2D2E2F2G2H2, instead of A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2? (without using the google script version)

Comment: @Kintaro: Yes there is, just substitute the spaces with nothing. =ArrayFormula(substitute(transpose(query(transpose(A2:H8),,50000)), " ",))

Comment: #JVPOk, I will abuse your help now... and how about if I add a static string for every transposed cell value and one of that transposed string is not there (example C2)? In my case the result is: 

formula: `=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(query(TRANSPOSE('sheet2'!$Z$2 & 'sheet2'!Y5:AC1000 & "|"),,50000))," ",))`

results: `STATICSTRINGA2|STATICSTRINGB2|STATICSTRING|STATICSTRINGD2|`

how to get rid of the C2's "STATIC" and have this instead? `STATICSTRINGA2|STATICSTRINGB2|STATICSTRINGD2|`

Comment: @JVP I solved adding a REGEXREPLACE in front of the SUBSTITUTE formula.

Comment: can you maybe explain this more? It looks so cdyptic

Answer (score -2):

**`=A2&" "&B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&" "&G2&" "&H2`**

**`=JOIN(" "; A2:H2)`**

**SORTED ROW: `=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(JOIN(" ";A2:H2));1;TRUE))` 
AND THEN: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>⇩ DOWN ARROW</kbd>** **...** **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**