# ArrayFormula expand to a whole column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have this formula that splits 7 columns into 84 columns.

```
=arrayformula(SPLIT(arrayformula(join(";",rept(B2:H2&";",12))),";"))
```

I'd like to use the arrayformula but for the entire rows without having to copy the formula.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:
=arrayformula(SPLIT(arrayformula(join(";",rept(B2:B:H2:H&";",12))),";"))

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qtl_HVMHelT59-ysk8q0-CzuxOt9RWLbYe0ANUW9G6U/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN()` only accepts a 1 dimensional array argument so we need to use other functions to 'join' the entries:

You can use:

```
=ArrayFormula(split(transpose(query(transpose(rept(B2:H8&";",12)),,50000)),";"))
```

Sample Sheet:

[image]

References:

[Concatenate 2D array to single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847717/google-sheets-concatenate-a-2d-array-into-a-single-column-and-sort-simultaneousl)

[TRANSPOSE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)

[QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: Works very well! Thank you Carlos